# How to add a toast to this view onFinishInflate

Tags: java, android, toast

I am brand new to android and i was wondering if it was possible to add toast onFinishInflate. If this is a stupid question please excuse me.I have created a view like this.

```
    import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.Canvas;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.Paint;
        import android.graphics.Rect;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomView extends View {

    private Rect rectangle;
    private Paint paint;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        int x = 50;
        int y = 50;
        int sideLength = 200;

        // create a rectangle that we'll draw later
        rectangle = new Rect(x, y, sideLength, sideLength);

        // create the Paint and set its color
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onfinishinflate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: You would use `getContext()` instead of `getApplicationContext()` in the `Toast`. However, that class can't be inflated, as is. You would need to provide a public, two-parameter constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

View has it's own method called `getContext()`, so you can use like this

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onfinishinflate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456214/7765316)

---

```
private Context context;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;

// Rest of ur codes
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    Toast.makeText(context, "onfinishinflate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

set the context in your class using constructor, and use it for Toast purpose